# Group rows with Id from specific row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been breaking my head trying to work this out, so some help here would be appreciated very much.

Basically I've got a database table, for example:

[image]

I'm trying to get the below result:

```
Id     | Name  | Total
------------------------
590954 | ABC   | 825.00
```

So I need the ID from the row with the largest Value for this group (i.e. ABC), the Name and the sum of Value (for this group - ABC).

There are many more rows with different names.

Thanks in advance.

Edit (adding some SQL to help out):

```
declare     @Test       table
    (       Id          int
    ,       Name        nvarchar(20)
    ,       Value       decimal(10,2)
    )

insert into @Test values (590954, 'ABC', 525)
insert into @Test values (592332, 'ABC', 300)
insert into @Test values (1, 'DEF', 100)
insert into @Test values (2, 'DEF', 250)

select * from @Test
```

The result I'm trying to get is these 2 rows:

```
Id     | Name  | Total
------------------------
590954 | ABC   | 825.00
2      | DEF   | 350.00
```

Please help me in writing the required query.

Comment: With as much rep as you have you should know we would like to have something to work with. That means sample data and desired output in a consumable format. The query itself here is pretty simple. It is going to take longer to setup the problem then write the code.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER () (partition by Name order by VALUE DESC)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[SQL DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/02110/2)

You can try the following query :

```
select t1.id, t1.name, t2.Total
from table1 t1
join(SELECT name, MAX(Value) as max_Value, SUM(Value) as Total
    FROM Table1 GROUP BY name) t2 
    on t1.name=t2.name and t1.Value=t2.max_Value
```

**To understand the query :** The derived table aliased as `t2` which contains the fields `name` , max `Value` and sum of `Value` of each group. Then it is joined with the main table `table1` with this condition `t1.name=t2.name and t1.Value=t2.max_Value` which confirms to select only the record which have the max `Value` of each group.

Comment: @Richard - Consider [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if your problem is sorted out.

Answer (score 4):

This is normally done using `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by value desc) as seqnum,
             sum(value) over (partition by name) as sumvalue
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: @HoneyBadger . . . I missed that in the question.  It is easy to add in.

Comment: Still this doesn't sum `Value` as expected. Perhaps you still didn't notice this line `So I need the ID from the row with the largest Value for this group (i.e. ABC), the Name and the sum of Value (for this group - ABC).`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample code similar to your requirement

```
Create table #temp2(id int,name varchar(3),val int)
Insert into #temp2 values (1,'ABC',20),(2,'ABC',40),(3,'PQR',10),(4,'PQR',30),(5,'PQR',50)

    Select id, name,Val from(
select id,name,Sum(val)over(partition by name) as Val,row_number()over(partition by name order by val desc)as Rn from #temp2 )t
where Rn=1
```

Comment: If I change the value of 1 from 20 to 10, then also I get the Id as 2

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using a Window function.  Similar to Gordon Linoff's answer, but I changed the partition in the sum(value) to get the correct answer:

```
    select t.*
    from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by value  desc) as seqnum,
         sum(value) over (partition by name) as sumvalue
    from @Test t
     ) t
    where seqnum = 1;
```